# LDPC codes - posterior probability and log-likelihood ratios

Tags: information-theory, coding-theory

I have a simple question regarding the transmission of binary data over a Binary Symmetric Channel (BSC) using LDPC codes.

Let's assume that the input message $x\in[0,1]$ is encoded using binary LDPC codes and transmitted over BSC. At the receiver side, the LDPC decoder based on belief propagation (sum-product algorithm) decodes the message and output the soft information $y$ in the form of log-likelihood ratios.

My question is that is it possible to determine $P(x=0|y)$ or $P(x=1|y)$ directly using the soft information $y$ i.e. the reliability about the decoded information is also reflected in the above mentioned probability calculation.

PS: The a priori probability $P(x)$ is also known at the decoder.

For example:

If we represent the variable nodes (output) of LDPC decoder by a random variable $L$ which can take on values from $+\infty$ to $-\infty$ (log likelihood ratios), for example, how to determine $Pr(x=0|l=+2.00)$ or $Pr(x=1|l=-3.00)$

Comment: I don't see anything unclear here. So you have the LLR as well as the prior probabilities and want to calculate the posterior probabilities. Isn't that the case?

Comment: Yes, you are right. However, I don't know how to do that. I'm very new to that field.

Answer (score 0):

$$\text{LLR}=\log\left(\frac{\Pr(x=0|y)}{\Pr(x=1|y)}\right)$$
with known LLR, and using the fact that $$\Pr(x=0|y)+\Pr(x=1|y)=1$$
You can find each of the two probabilities.

Comment: Is this what you meant in the question?

Comment: Actually, I mean that consider the output of the LDPC decoder as a random variable $L$, then how to calculate $Pr(x=0|l)$. Don't we need to know the pdf of $L$?

Comment: The output (as well as the input) of the LDPC decoder is again a LLR, that I gave you its definition.